# JSON stored as string. Cant seem to parse it - Java

Tags: java, json

This is what I have to read text in JSON format from a website. But i get the error

> Java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be
>   cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray

This is driving me nuts. Can anyone help? I also need to check this string for all instances of "Username" and run something for each of them.

```
public class CommandCheck implements CommandExecutor {
private String username;
private static String host = "example.com";
private URL url;
private String apiKey = main.getNode("API-KEY");
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] arg3) {
    try {
        this.url = new URL(CommandCheck.host);
        final URLConnection conn = this.url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);

        if (this.apiKey != null) {
            conn.addRequestProperty("x-api-key", this.apiKey);
        }
        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", main.USER_AGENT);

        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        final String response = reader.readLine();
        sender.sendMessage(response); //Im just dumping the raw String for the person running the command to see Debug mostly
        final JSONArray array = (JSONArray) JSONValue.parse(response);

        if (array.isEmpty()) {
            sender.sendMessage("The Array appears to be empty");
            return false;
        }
        JSONObject latestUpdate = (JSONObject) array.get(array.size() - 1);
        username = (String) latestUpdate.get("Username");
        sender.sendMessage("whitelist add" + username);
        return true;
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        if (e.getMessage().contains("HTTP response code: 403")) {
            sender.sendMessage("I think there is an API key issue");
        } else {
            sender.sendMessage("Problem of unknown orign");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't include the string in question. Betting it's an object instead of an array, just like the error says.

Comment: { "redemptions":[ { "reward_id":450491, "redemption_id":1729333, "created_at":"2017-01-05T00:42:41.949Z", "refunded":false, "completed":false, "user_input": { "Minecraft Username":"Budderb123" }, "username":"budderbb123" }, { "reward_id":450491, "redemption_id":1729314, "created_at":"2017-01-05T00:41:08.881Z", "refunded":false, "completed":false, "user_input": { "Minecraft Username":"Bigdaddy" }, "username":"dustinduse" } ], "total":2, "page_size":25 }

Comment: Yeah, that's a JSON object with top-level keys `redemptions`, `total`, and `page_size`. Not an array.

Comment: Ok. So i need to convert to an array first then? Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the following line:

`final JSONArray array = (JSONArray) JSONValue.parse(response);`

to:

`final JSONObject jsObj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(response);`

Can you provide the JSON String you are trying to parse? I.e. the value of `response`?

Comment: {
 "redemptions":[
  {
  "reward_id":450491,
  "redemption_id":1729333,
  "created_at":"2017-01-05T00:42:41.949Z",
  "refunded":false,
  "completed":false,
  "user_input":
   {
   "Minecraft Username":"Budderb123"
   },
  "username":"budderbb123"
  },
  {
  "reward_id":450491,
  "redemption_id":1729314,
  "created_at":"2017-01-05T00:41:08.881Z",
  "refunded":false,
  "completed":false,
  "user_input":
   {
   "Minecraft Username":"Bigdaddy"
   },
  "username":"dustinduse"
  }
 ],
 "total":2,
 "page_size":25
}

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(response.readEntity(String.class)));
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonReader.readArray();
ListIterator l = jsonArray.listIterator();
while ( l.hasNext() ) {
      JsonObject j = (JsonObject)l.next();
      JsonObject ciAttr = j.getJsonObject("ciAttributes") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray means that you are trying to convert the json object into the json array. if your response in the json object as a response then you first need it to convert in the Json object.

after converting you can get the the Json array from the json object using the get("key-name")

```
JSONObject resObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
JSONArray resArray = resObj.getJSONArray("Username");
for (int i=0; i<resArray.length(); i++)
String resultString = resArray.getString(i);
```

it gives you all usersname.

i think this code helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: This answer makes the most sense to me. How do i convert Object to array?